# automatically start and and selectively stop multiple instances of couchdb on osx

Tags: mac-osx, unix, shell, couchdb, nosql

I have successfully installed couchdb via homebrew:

```
% brew install couchdb
```

...and invoked mutiple instances as directed [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AU_z9pbiQzoJ:wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Additional_Instances%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari):

```
% OLD=/usr/local
% NEW=/tmp/couchdb

% mkdir -p $NEW/etc/couchdb/
% mkdir -p $NEW/var/{lib,log,run}/couchdb/

% cp $OLD/etc/couchdb/local.ini $NEW/etc/couchdb/
```

local.ini changes:

```
[couchdb]
database_dir = /tmp/couchdb/var/lib/couchdb
view_index_dir = /tmp/couchdb/var/lib/couchdb
uri_file = /tmp/couchdb/var/run/couchdb/couch.uri

[httpd]
port = 5985
bind_address = 0.0.0.0

[log]
file = /tmp/couchdb/var/log/couchdb/couch.log
```

... and startup the startup command:

```
% couchdb -i -a /tmp/couchdb/etc/couchdb/local.ini
```

Now that I have this working, how can I start up each instance on boot, and if I wanted to kill an instance (preferred by name or some known identifier), how might selectively do that?  I'm running OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.3 (with Xcode command line tools) in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The OS X way to start things at boot is `launchd`, specifically a `LaunchDaemon`. For a complete understanding, it's worthwhile to read [the Apple documentation on `launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html); also, there are many questions and answers here to help you.

The short version is, you'll need a file, eg `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.inator.couchdb` that looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.inator.couchdb</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/couchdb</string>
        <string>-i</string>
        <string>-a</string>
        <string>/tmp/couchdb/etc/couchdb/local.ini</string>
    </array>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note that this will run as `root`; if you want it to run as a particular user, you'll need to use `sudo` (eg `sudo -u inator /usr/local/couchdb …`).

To start and the job manually, you can `load` and `unload` it from `launchd` using `launchctl`, eg:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.inator.couchdb
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.inator.couchdb
```

If you want another instance, just create a new file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` with a different filename (and a matching `Label`).